# Emulation of an infrared input?

Tags: infrared, emulation, device-emulation

I am currently working on creating applications for this device:

http://www.eonreality.com/eon-ibench-mobile

I do not have 24 hour access to the device and was wondering if it was possible to emulate the tracking system used in the above device. 
Such as the IR Glasses & IR stylus. Is there any software that can emulate IR devices on a windows based system..

Thanks